# PyDev code analysis missing

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I have installed Eclipse 3.7.2 from APT in Ubuntu 12.04, and installed PyDev in Eclipse. First, it warns unused import and unused wild import, but it no longer displays them today. However, it can display errors like missing parenthesis.

I created a new user, and installed PyDev using that user, problem still happens. How can I enable them for warnings? I have not change the code analysis settings.

Comment: have you add project directory to PYTHONPATH when you setting your pydev?

Comment: you can also remove your python interpretor settings, and set it again in eclipse - window - preference - pydev -interpreter Python, refresh the pydev index

Comment: @pinkdawn  when creating the project, the default "Add project directory to PYTHONPATH?" is checked. But when I check it in Project -> Properties -> PyDev -PYTHONPATH, all is empty. I then "add source folder". Now names import from subdirs are all "undefined variable"...

Comment: @pinkdawn Reset interpreter settings, but problem still occurs.

Comment: @pinkdawn I remove the project and recreated it, and this time the project dir is the the PYTHONPATH, and problem disappears. If you reply it in answer, I'd have accepted it. :) Thank you.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

list all operations could solve it here, for others convenience, and make this question closed

- remove the project and recreated it, and this time the project dir is the the PYTHONPATH
- remove your python interpretor settings, and set it again in eclipse - window preference - pydev -interpreter Python, refresh the pydev index
- Project -> Properties -> PyDev -PYTHONPATH, all is empty. I then "add source folder"

Comment: Try the third step [Add source folder] first and only if it fails, try others. Will save you so much effort.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem. Went to project properties > pydev - PYTHONPATH, then setting the source folder did it for me !