# PyDev ignores errors

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I'm working through a Python exercise in Eclipse which is deliberately laced with errors. The problem is, PyDev is not raising errors, or even warnings - the script runs fine in the Eclipse console. If I had written it myself, I'd have no idea there was anything wrong. Go and run the script in IDLE however, and the errors duly halt the script.

I've tried the solution suggested [elsewhere on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11326522/pydev-code-analysis-missing) to no avail.

Comment: What is the source code, and what errors do you recieve?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but just fixed it. In Run>Run Configurations, "Main Module" was pointing to a working version of the script. Now Eclipse is throwing up the errors that it should.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, answered my own question (-_-)

In Run>Run Configurations, "Main Module" was pointing to a working version of the script.

Now Eclipse is throwing up the errors that it should.

Comment: Great that you found it. As a note, if you have the file opened, use `F9` to run it (and the `Ctrl+F11` to rerun the last launch -- take a look at the manual: http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_run.html for more tips).